# How can i log custom store events in a windows cordova app

Tags: cordova, windows-store

I have built and uploaded a windows store app, compiled with cordova. My app works fine however there is one feature that I cant seem to crack. Custom events of the app usage.

I wanted to know how can I use custom events in a cordova app, because I was unable to find any instructions to use it in a cordova project.

[image]

The link leads to [the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/log-custom-events-for-dev-center), but it only explains how to do this for UWP apps. Maybe I could write a plugin for this, but I don't know how to reference `Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement` in a javascript plugin file.

This functionality isn't essential to my app, but it would be really nice to have custom events, so any pointers and help will be appreciated.